# In GWT 2.0 CssResource, how to "print" GWT.getModuleBaseURL()

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I have a class that references a background image (and I don't want to upgrade to using imagebundles) so I need to print the "base module url" before my image url. How can I achieve this?

```
background: #BDE5F8 url("image/info.png") no-repeat 2px center;
```

Comment: You can avoid this trouble by including your "image" directory at the same level as your host page. Whenever you deploy, the relative path to the directory will be the same, regardless of the base module url.

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a static function somewhere:

```
public static String getBackgroundUrl(){
     return com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.getModuleName() + "/images/background.png";
}
```

And in your CSS

```
@eval BG_URL com.yourclass.getBackgroundUrl();

.myBackground { background-url:BG_URL; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Including images in your ClientBundle really is the way to go. But then again, you've already mentioned that you're not going to do that.

Instead, consider using a [value function](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Value_function) to get the value of `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()`:

```
.something {
    background: #BDE5F8 value('com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.getModuleBaseURL', '/info.png') no-repeat 2px center;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work:

[INFO]                   Performing substitution in node background : .....
[INFO] ;
[INFO] 
[INFO]                      [ERROR] Could not find no-arg method named com in type com.xxx.protocol.xxx.web.gwt.xxx.client.clientbundle.ClientBundle